Rollback to a previous proxmox snapshot without losing the current zfs snapshot?
Using proxmox with ZFS storage pools, is it possible to restore an LXC container or QEMU Virtual Machine to an earlier snapshot (not the most recent snapshot) without losing or destroying any snapshots?
Attempting to do this using the Proxmox GUI presents an error message:

can't rollback, 'snapshotname' is not most recent snapshot on 'storage:vmname'

Asked another way, is it possible to have non-linear snapshots? For example, a tree of snapshots that looks like this, where there's a true "tree" with branches, and some snapshots have more than one child?

Multiple sources on the internet appear to indicate not (example 1 or example 2) but I know that's incorrect because I have done this :)

Yes, despite multiple forum posts and the documentation indicating this is only possible with qcow2, it's doable fairly easily using the command line and ZFS clones:

Identify the current ZFS snapshots which represent the snapshot you want to roll back to. You can check the VM or LXC config file under /etc/pve/qemu-server/ or /etc/pve/lxc/ if you're unsure. Use zfs list (possibly combined with grep as needed) to locate them.
For this example, assume I am working on LXC container ID 113, so my ZFS filesystems are rpool/data/lxc/subvol-113-disk-0@creation and rpool/data/lxc/subvol-113-disk-1@creation

Clone the snapshots of all relevant volumes and produce new ZFS datasets using zfs clone $dataset@$snapshot $new_dataset. I tend to set the new dataset name to the next available disk number, but you can select almost any new name you please:
zfs clone rpool/data/lxc/subvol-113-disk-0@creation rpool/data/lxc/subvol-113-disk-2
zfs clone rpool/data/lxc/subvol-113-disk-1@creation rpool/data/lxc/subvol-113-disk-3


Edit the VM or LXC config file (under /etc/pve/qemu-server or /etc/pve/lxc) and make two changes: update the paths to the volumes and set the parent property to the name of the snapshot you are rolling back to (creation in my example)

For an LXC container, you'll edit the rootfs argument as well as any mp$n arguments
For a VM, you'll edit scsi$n lines, or ide$n lines if you're using IDE disks


The UI should now show a snapshot tree and everything should work as expected. You can create new snapshots as normal. If you want to revert to the previous tree, you'll need to edit the configuration file and adjust the parent as well as revert/adjust the storage lines you edited.


